# Plugin.MediaManager does not play sound. MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@a3fcfe6): Cookies: null

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms

MediaManager does not play sound.
I add a button and set a command to play sound but It doesn't play any sound, gives error like below.

```
PLAY CLICKED
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=2084.98ms min=1.45ms max=91444.75ms count=44
[MediaHTTPService] MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@a3fcfe6): Cookies: null
[MediaHTTPService] makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@c370f87) exists.
[MediaHTTPService] makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@a3fcfe6): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@c370f87 Cookies: null
```

Command :

```
 Console.WriteLine("PLAY CLICKED");
        var streamUrl = "https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3";
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(streamUrl);
```

That is my app.xaml.cs :

```
public App()
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

What should I do in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, did you [initialize the plugin](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#important-initialize-plugin) in the android project? The official document said:

> Select Plugin.MediaManager and
> install into each project within your solution. Make sure to call Init() in all the native platforms on startup of your app.

You can try to initialize it in the `MainActivity's OnCreate` method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
}
```

And then you can try to set the speed for the media player before playing the audio:

```
float speed = 1;  
CrossMediaManager.Current.Speed = speed; 
var streamUrl = "https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3";
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(streamUrl);
```

Comment: When I add this to MainActivity's OnCreate It gives this error : `com.companyname.internetradioplayer: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.'
`

Comment: I don't use any pending intent.

Comment: This is because the package version is too old. You can try the `Plugin.MediaManager 1.1.1`. In addion, if it still don't work. You can ignore the first step and only do the second step (set the speed for the player). @MertAltiparmak

Comment: I tried update version `Plugin.MediaManager 1.1.1` and somehow It could play sound. Thanks a lot. App works like this.